# Define a pervasive function in APL

Tags: apl

How can one define a pervasive function in APL?

What I do is

```
function←{
    (⊃⍣(⍬≡⍴⍵)){the function that apply to scalar}¨⍵
}
```

I think there should be a better way to do this that I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

Most primitive functions in APL are already pervasive.  So, unless you do fancy stuff, your custom functions will already be pervasive.  For instance

```
f←{÷1+*-⍵}    ⍝ sigmoid, f(x)=1/(1+exp(-x))
```

will work on arrays as well as scalars.

If you do do fancy stuff and you have a non-pervasive function `f`, you can turn it into a 
pervasive one by

```
g←{0=⍴⍴⍵:f⍵ ⋄ ∇¨⍵}   ⍝ the pervasive version of f
```

which can be read as: if the argument is a scalar, apply `f` on it, otherwise recursively go into each item of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The [`dfns` workspace](http://dfns.dyalog.com/) contains the [`perv` operator](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_perv.htm) which causes its operand function to be applied pervasively, with either one or two arguments:

```
perv←{⍺←⊢               ⍝ Scalar pervasion
    1=≡⍺ ⍵ ⍵:⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵     ⍝ (⍺ and) ⍵ depth 0: operand fn application
             ⍺ ∇¨⍵      ⍝ (⍺ or) ⍵ deeper: recursive traversal.
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBJrJ@QWVCilpecUKBalFZQopmcUFXHmpxSWpKY/aJmioJyapK6gnp6Sqa2qop6VnADkZmVnqmlwgdQoQdRC2eqK6gg7YCIgoAA)